# accessing list of images in orchard cms  OR including mediapicker field in razor view of module

Tags: orchardcms

I am writing a module for an orchard site that contains forms for data entry into a non-orchard database. via this user interface,
I would like to save images in the file system/orchard database via the mediapicker module, 
and also save the url for the images to the "other" database.

What is the best way to accomplish this taks?

It seems there are 2 main options:

1.incorporate the media picker field into the view on my module.

using "recipe"?

1. Access a list of media objects in the orchard cms (by folder). then I can display these in a dropwdown in my module.
   (users will need to go to the mediapicker moudule to upload images)

   using  the namespace Orchard.Media.Services 
   in order to access the MediaService class ?
   I am unable to find the dll for this namespace.

I am using ocrchard version 1.4

Comment: In what form are the images stored in the database? Do you have content parts that have Image fields (MediaPickerField) attached to them? If that's not it, please describe.

Comment: ALso, are you able to write code or do you need to do this through the UI only? I'm not sure the latter is possible, but it might be, using the very awesome Projections module.

Comment: I doing this all through code. I am writing a data entry module for an external database. The images are being stored using the mediapicker module, via the ui. ideally, i would be able to use the media picker field in my razor view, but I don't know how to include this field in a module that I write in code.

Comment: I am trying to do this using the MediaService class. its constructor recevies iorchardprovider and iorchardservices.  Do I need to create an instance of these, or can/how do I pass in the defaults of the orchard application?

Comment: You don't instantiate the MediaService class yourself, and you don't need to worry about what parameters its constructor has. If you need to use IMediaSErvice from your class, take in a param of type  IMediaService in your class's constructor. Orchard (or rather, Autofac) will construct and pass that in to your class.